# Is this possible to lock the mouse along a path and if so how?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I want to be able to lock a mouse to move along an arc only. Is this possible? And if so how? I have tried looking on Google and forums. All I have found are locking movieclips to a path. I am using ActionScript 3 in Adobe Flash CS6.

Comment: I dont think you can restrict the actual cursor, if you are trying to lock like the movement of of an object that is controlled by the mouse in your scene you can do that by checking the current position of the mouse and then detect if its within the range of x,y coords that your arc path flows through.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. However, as I am new to as3 (started 2 mths ago) I understand what you are talking about but I cant seem to formulate a code so could you help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133224/how-to-check-if-mouse-is-over-a-movieclip this may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- hide the mouse cursor
- create a custom cursor (like actual cursor)
- change position of your cursor (use mouse position)

this code will give you an idea

```
Mouse.hide();
var path:Array=[new Point(0,0),new Point(50,20),new Point(150,40),new Point(250,60),new Point(300,70),new Point(400,80)];
var myCursor:Sprite=new Sprite();
myCursor.graphics.beginFill(0);
myCursor.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,5);
myCursor.graphics.endFill();
addChild(myCursor);

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,refreshCursorPosition);
function refreshCursorPosition(e:MouseEvent):void{
    if(e.stageX<0 || e.stageX>stage.stageWidth)
        return;
    var pos:int=Math.floor(e.stageX*path.length/stage.stageWidth);
    myCursor.x=path[pos].x;
    myCursor.y=path[pos].y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This documentation might be what you're looking for.
http://evolve.reintroducing.com/2011/05/09/as3/as3-drag-a-clip-along-an-arc/

Take a look at the example first.