# Datagrid select multiple item by click and drag

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

Is there a way to select multiple items in a `DataGrid` by clicking and dragging (i.e. - clicking the top item and dragging mouse to items below will select them all)?

I have the `allowMultipleSelection` enabled so I can select multiple items using the <kbd>shift</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> keys, however is there a way to do this with only a **mouse click**?

Even if `allowDragSelection` is enabled, it doesn't work.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You could do...

```
    private function mouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, handleMouseMove);
    }

    private function handleMouseMove(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        //Code to get display object if mouseX and Y is intercepting a cell
        //Tell said cell that it has been selected
    }

    private function mouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, handleMouseMove);
    }
```

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133224/how-to-check-if-mouse-is-over-a-movieclip) a few was from a quick search on how to detect if a mouse is over a display object. Apply that and you're set.